# Different View tree on different APIs

Tags: android, layout

I need to get views within Activity and get them in same way on all phones and API versions.
Here is how I do it:

```
private void walkTroughViews(ViewGroup group)
{
    for (int i=0; i<group.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);

        if (something)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
            walkTroughViews(viewGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

But the results are different based on API level or phone model(not sure yet)
It seems that on 4.2 there is one LinearLayout and on >4.0 there is frame layout that is not on 4.1 or 4.1. 
Why is that and how can I get only Activity layout that is identical on all phones? 
Currently I am trying to start this method in `onGlobalLayoutListener` `mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.content)`

P.S. I think it might be because of `support-v4` library, but why is there spare LinearLayout on 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

libraries and native components of different APIs can generate different layout. This is for tab activity and action bar, progress bar and others. I normally check the viewtree using ui automator viewer, it is quite handy check this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html
and this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html